# Access last row added to table - PHP

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a simple sql query adding a new row to a database and need it to return the a field back to Javascript. The field does Auto_increment but stupildy I called it 'itemId' so `mysql_insert_id` doesnt work and I don't think I have time to go and amend all the php files that use 'itemId'

Here's my code if it helps:

```
$addMainItem = "INSERT INTO newsItems (itemId, title, date, tags, location, latitude, longitude, visibleFrontpage, introText, fullDome, liveEvent, customServing, visitorAttraction, retail, digitalCinema, visiblePublic, thumbPath, links, smallDesc) VALUES ('','$title','$date','$tags','$loco','$lat','$long','$visiFront','$intro','$dome ','$live','$custom','$attrac','$retail','$cinema','$public','$thumbPath','$links','$smallDesc')";
$result = mysql_query($addMainItem) or die('error '.mysql_error());

if($result) echo (mysql_insert_id());
```

Comment: there shouldn't be a problem with your field name. The function actually looks for the first field of the type 'auto_increment' that was updated with the last query. From php.net: "Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT)."

Comment: Ahh, Well you are correct. It seems because I had the connection in a seperate php file being included it returned undefined. When I moved the connection PHP into the same file it started working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard that naming a column itemId breaking mysql_isert_id().

But you can just select the last inserted record if auto_increment is working.

```
SELECT * FROM newsItems ORDER BY itemId DESC LIMIT 1
```

You can put the select statement into a transaction with the insert statement if you're using innoDB and you're worried about a race condition.

Comment: Turns out itemId was not the problem and mysql_isert_id() did work when I moved some of my php into the same file.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
```

Isn't it what are you looking for?